# Convert query result types when using fetchall()

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pymssql

I am writing a Python database data backup script targeting an instance of Microsoft SQL Server 2012. My goal is to be able to easily backup a database's data to an existing empty schema. I am using pymssql as my database interface.

Here is the section of code I am having problems with:

```
def run_migrate(s_conn, d_conn): 
    source_cursor = s_conn.cursor()
    dest_cursor = d_conn.cursor()
    source_cursor.execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES order by TABLE_NAME asc")
    res_tables = source_cursor.fetchall()
    tables = [i[0] for i in res_tables]
    for i in range(len(tables)): 
        query_columns = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + str(tables[i]) + "'"
        l.log.debug(query_columns)
        source_cursor.execute(query_columns)
        res_columns = source_cursor.fetchall()
        columns = [i[0] for i in res_columns]
        query_data = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tables[i]
        l.log.debug(query_data)
        source_cursor.execute(query_data)
        res_results = source_cursor.fetchall()
        l.log.info('Extracted ' + str(len(results))  + ' results from ' + tables[i])
```

My problem is that when i use `res_results = fetchall()` I get back a list that looks like the following:

```
<class 'list'>: [(Decimal('102'), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 29, 13, 53, 20, 593000), '1459281200561077E9152BF85FCBC33E6689E9DCB61705985137701459280466827', 'cable summary ', 3600000, 0, None, None, None, None, None, None, 0, 0, None, None, Decimal('333'), Decimal('100'), Decimal('107'), None, None)]
```

I am looking to form a parameterized INSERT statement out of this data to run against `d_conn.execute()` but how can I convert the data types on the fly without knowing beforehand each columns data type and how to handle it?

For example I would need the convert the list:

```
<class 'list'>: [
(Decimal('102'), 
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 29, 13, 53, 20, 593000),
'1459281200561077E9152BF85FCBC33E6689E9DCB61705985137701459280466827', 
'cable summary ', 
3600000, 
0, 
None, 
None, 
None, 
None, 
None, 
None, 
0, 
0, 
None, 
None, 
Decimal('333'), 
Decimal('100'), 
Decimal('107'), 
None, 
None)]
```

into the SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO [ALERT] VALUES
   (102
   ,'2016-03-29 13:53:20.593'
   ,1
   ,'cable summary'
   ,3600000
   ,0
   ,NULL
   ,NULL
   ,NULL
   ,NULL
   ,NULL
   ,NULL
   ,0
   ,0
   ,NULL
   ,NULL
   ,333
   ,100
   ,107
   ,NULL
   ,NULL)
```

I want to be able to do this with any datatypes I pass it as I have a few hundred tables to do this with and don't want to write a function for each one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the Force and an ORM, Luke. sqlalchemy is on the light side and has support for pymssql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example I would need the convert the list ... into the [literal] SQL INSERT statement ...

Actually, no you wouldn't, at least not if you really did use a parameterized query for the INSERT. Python's DB-API specifies generic parameter placeholders and relies on the database access layer (e.g., pymssql) to figure out how to handle parameters based on the type of parameter *values* supplied.

So, you can simply take the list of rows (which contain values of the appropriate type) from the source table and use those rows as parameter values for an `executemany` on the target table, like so:

```python
# set up test
create_stmt = """\
CREATE TABLE {} (
    intCol INT PRIMARY KEY,
    nvarcharCol NVARCHAR(50),
    datetimeCol DATETIME,
    decimalCol DECIMAL(18,4),
    nullableCol INT
    )
"""
crsr.execute(create_stmt.format("#MainTable"))
load_test_data = """\
INSERT INTO #MainTable (intCol, nvarcharCol, datetimeCol, decimalCol) VALUES
    (1, N'test 1', '2016-01-01', 1.11),
    (2, N'test 2', '2016-02-02', 2.22),
    (3, N'test 3', '2016-03-03', 3.33)
"""
crsr.execute(load_test_data)
crsr.execute(create_stmt.format("#BackupTable"))

# perform the copy ...
read_stmt = """\
SELECT * FROM #MainTable
"""
crsr.execute(read_stmt)
source_rows = crsr.fetchall()
# ... using a true parameterized query ...
write_stmt = """\
INSERT INTO #BackupTable
        (intCol, nvarcharCol, datetimeCol, decimalCol, nullableCol)
    VALUES
        (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
"""
# ... inserting all rows at once using list returned by fetchall() from source table
crsr.executemany(write_stmt, source_rows)

#check results
crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM #BackupTable")
print("Rows from #BackupTable:")
for row in crsr.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

... producing:

```
Rows from #BackupTable:
(1, 'test 1', datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0), Decimal('1.1100'), None)
(2, 'test 2', datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 2, 0, 0), Decimal('2.2200'), None)
(3, 'test 3', datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 3, 0, 0), Decimal('3.3300'), None)
```